# Laravel 5.0 sync() on relation not working when storing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model Mailgroup and a model CommunicationType.

I Mailgroup can have multiple CommuniationType's. This is my relation:

Mailgroup model:

```
public function communicationTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommunicationType');
}
```

CommunicationType model:

```
public function mailgroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ImageRequest');
}
```

This the code I do to try and store a new Mailgroup.

```
$data = $this->request->all();
$mailgroup = new Mailgroup($data);
$mailgroup->communicationTypes()->sync($data['communication_types']);
```

Result of $data:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "j8lcEMggCakzANNbeVLYZttdOLUwJYKIJi0m85e6"
  "name" => "a"
  "administrator" => "abc"
  "communication_types" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "a"
    1 => "a"
  ]
  "site_id" => 4
]
```

The error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does `$data['communication_types']` contain?

Comment: an array of strings that need to be stored in the communication_types table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `sync` method for one-to-many relations, you will have to use `save` or `saveMany`.

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models):

> Eloquent provides convenient methods for adding new models to
>   relationships. For example, perhaps you need to insert a new Comment
>   for a Post model. Instead of manually setting the  post_id attribute
>   on the Comment, you may insert the Comment directly from the
>   relationship's  save method:

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

> If you need to save multiple related models, you may use the saveMany
>   method:

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->saveMany([
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
]);
```

Comment: How do I cerate that array for the saveMany() parameter? do I need to loop over my $data[communication_types] ?

Comment: yes either loop through your data or if your data has valid attributes for the model you can use `createMany` instead of `saveMany`

Answer (score 0):

Mailgroup hasn't been saved yet. Save/create it first and then sync:

```
$data = $this->request->all();
$mailgroup = Mailgroup::create($data);
$mailgroup->communicationTypes()->sync($data['communication_types']);
```

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately it gives the same error

Comment: Ah, than you should use [Remuls Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55723792/1336174). But remember to save the Mailgroup first! Otherwise the mailgroup won't have an ID yet.